# Why does complete'ing requests where JavaUUID is used lead to compilation error?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I'm developing a project with Akka and Spray. It works fine except `GET`s that are handled with the following route:

```
class UserRoot extends Directives with DefaultJsonFormats with PerRequestCreator {
  val route =
    path("users" / JavaUUID / "activities") { userId =>
      get {
        complete {
          createActorPerRequest(new StringUUID(userId), Props[LogicGetActivitiesFromUser])
        }
      }
    }

  def createActorPerRequest(entity: Entity, target: Props): Route =
     context => perRequest(context, target, Work(entity))
}
```

The `StringUUID` class:

```
case class StringUUID(id: String) extends Entity // I also tried UUID instead of String
```

The code above errors with the following:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.UUID
 required: String
       createActorPerRequest(new StringUUID(userId), Props[LogicGetActivitiesFromUser])
```

But if I add `import reflect.ClassTag` (that I found this on the internet) it gives me another error:

```
error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller[spray.routing.RequestContext => Unit]
createActorPerRequest(new StringUUID(userId.toString), Props[LogicGetActivitiesFromUser])
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [Example](https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/spray-actor-per-request/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/netaporter/routing/RestRouting.scala). It doesn't have the `complete`.

The following `route` should fix the error:

```
val route = 
  path("pets") {
    get {
      petsWithOwner {
        GetPetsWithOwners(List("Lassie"))
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the types don't match so the Scala compiler (not Spray or Akka or anything else) reports it as compilation error.

In the first version of the `route` code, mind the type of `userId` - it's `java.util.UUID` as the Scala compiler says. You can't use a val of `java.util.UUID` type where `String` is expected, in `StringUUID` for `id` input parameter.

In the second version of the code, in which you've used `userId.toString` the type `String` matches the expected type of the `id` input parameter. That led you to another issue where there was no implicit to marshall the response from `createActorPerRequest` as requested by `complete`.

You should let the spawn actor to `complete` the response or await a response from the actor (using the `ask` pattern) and pass it on as a response from `complete`. That also needs a marshaller (as were the code inside `complete` in the actor's `receive`).